# Cannot configure dbeaver in windows?

Tags: jar, driver, settings

I'm getting 'You should configure jars driver Settings error' while connecting Dbeaver to MySql. I already installed Java and JRE. Is the reason it is not able to find jre files.

image

[image]

How can i set this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably temporary directory issue. The driver tries to execute in temporary directory but needs admin right for that.
Try restarting DBeaver in admin mode ("Run as administrator").